# php mysql car parking query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Hey i need a bit mysql query help..
i have a table named **airport_car_parking** with 4 fields

> id [int autoincrement primary key]
>
> email [varchar]
>
> departure_date [DATETIME]
>
> arrival_date [DATETIME]

now i have two variables $departure_date [something in datetime format] and $arrival_date [something in datetime format]

I want to write a query in php - mysql that checks whether my booking days belongs into above table booking dates or not...

say if i consider my above table data like below

```
id | email | departure_date | arrival_date 

1 | abc@gmail.com | 2013-12-22 12.15.00 | 2013-12-25 12.15.00
```

so no one can book a car in those 3 days of dec 2013
i have two variable like

```
$departure_date= 2013-12-24 12.15.00   and 
$arrival_date= 2013-12-26 12.15.00
```

but a car can not be park in those days because table data shows that in this time already a car is booked... i need a query that checks any booking plot is available or not.

I write a query like below , but its valid only after existing period

```
$chk_date_sql="select * from airport_car_parking where return_date >= '$deperture_date'";
```

Comment: That's not terribly clear, I'm afraid - could you post an actual example? What is your booking days? What are the rules about whether it should be in the table or not?

Comment: Need to show us some code of what you've attempted thus far, and what isn't working.

Comment: say if i consider my above table data like below

**id | email | departure_date | arrival_date**

1  | abc@gmail.com | 2013-12-22 12.15.00 | 2013-12-25 12.15.00

so no one can book a car in those 3 days of dec 2012

i have two variable like $departure_date= 2013-12-24 12.15.00 and $arrival_date= 2013-12-26 12.15.00 , but a car can not be park in those days because table data shows that in this time already a car is booked... i need a query that checks any booking plot is available or not..

Comment: @Brett - could you please edit that into your question? It'll make it a lot easier to read!

Comment: @andrewsi i hv edited my question in details

Comment: @Brett - if I understand you right, then what you've got is a potential booking (1st December to 3rd December for example); and you need to make sure that there are no bookings already set up for those dates. I think you just need to check that there are no existing bookings that have a start date or an end date during the time of the query. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is referencing `return_date`, which isn't a column in the airport_car_parking table.

As for the logic of the query, you want to make sure that the $departure_date isn't between any row's `departure_date` or `arrival_date`. I would recommend the following query -

```
$chk_date_sql="SELECT * FROM airport_car_parking WHERE '$departure_date' BETWEEN departure_date AND arrival_date;";
```

And then that query returns with any rows, that means that the requested time **will not** work.